# Get the referenced value of a CSS variable

Tags: javascript, css

Given

```html
<div></div>

<style>
body {
  --var1: 3;
  --var2: var(--var1);
}

div {
  --var3: var(--var2);
  width: var(--var3);
}
</style>
```

How can I obtain the reference list of css variables?

```
getReferenceList(divElement, 'width')
```

Would result in

```
['--var3', '--var2', '--var1', 3]
```

Comment: Are you asking for a list of all css variables being used in a stylesheet? Or the values of a specific css variable being used?

Answer (score 2):

If you already know the property name, you can use [getComputedStyle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle). For instance,

```js
window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('body')).getPropertyValue('--var1');
```

This will return `3`.

If you would like to get a list of all stylesheets, you can use [CSSStyleSheet.cssRules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet/cssRules).

The following example will give you the stylesheet of `body`:

```
document.styleSheets[0].cssRules[0].cssText
```

So the result of it will be `"body { --var1: 3; --var2: var(--var1); }"`.

In your case, `cssRules[0]` = `body` and `cssRules[1]` = `div`.

You can also use `selectorText` to find out what tag it is. In this case `document.styleSheets[0].cssRules[0].selectorText` will return the string `body`.

If you prefer an array of properties and values, instead of a string, you can use this regex:

```js
const regex = /(?<={)[ -a-zA-Z0-9\S][^}]+/gm
const str = document.styleSheets[0].cssRules[0].cssText.match(regex);
console.log(str[0].split(';'));
```